# What is the meaning of ‘resolution’ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Our youth are impatient with the preliminaries that are essential to
> purposeful action. Effective organization is thwarted by the desire
> for instant and dramatic change, or as I have phrased it elsewhere the
> demand for revelation rather than revolution. It's the kind of thing
> we see in play writing; the first act introduces the characters and
> the plot, in the second act the plot and characters are developed as
> the play strives to hold the audience's attention. In the final act
> good and evil have their dramatic confrontation and **resolution**. (Source: Rules for Radicals by Saul Alinsky)

Which of the meanings of ‘resolution’ is meant above? I have seen the main meanings of the word and I cannot say which one is meant here.

I should add that, based on the writer’s phrasing, I understand the structure to be something like this: … good and evil have their dramatic confrontation and their dramatic resolution.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution** definition 3 from the ODE ( the one inbuilt into iPhones) says the following: *the action of solving a contentious matter or problem*

In my own words on this particular context I shall say the following; resolution can sometimes essentially mean end, if there be problems and twists and turns et cetera in the story. And in english story-writing and plays and the like, the resolution is often merely used to describe an end which satisfies the audience; for it resolves the central problem or contentious matter which comprises the story.

Comment: But it is the end of the story, not ‘their’ end. I edited the question.

Comment: I do not think you understand my comment. Resolution between good and evil, ( a firm decision to do or not to do something) a decision is reached after the conflict over what next to do. Really not that hard to get.

Comment: It's the situation in the (imaginary) play that is resolved.

Comment: A similar word is "climax", although this can also refer to the peak of action leading up to the resolution.